# Python: copy and paste files based on paths in two csvs

Tags: csv, numpy, pandas, shutil, file-copying

I have two csv files, one with a list of paths for source files, the second, a list of paths for where to copy the files to. Both files have the same number of elements and each source file is only copied once.

How would I load the .csv files (Pandas? Numpy? csv.reader?), and how would I copy all of the items in the best possible way? I am able to get the following to work if `src` and `dest` each refer to one path.

```
import pandas as pd
srcdf = pd.read_csv('src.csv')
destdf = pd.read_csv('dest.csv')

from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src,dest)
```

There are no headers or columns in my files. It's just a vector of comma-separated values. The comma-separated values in my `src` csv file are look like:

```
/Users/johndoe/Downloads/50.jpg,
/Users/johndoe/Downloads/51.jpg,
```

In my `dest` csv file are like:

```
/Users/johndoe/Downloads/newFolder/50.jpg,       
/Users/johndoe/Downloads/newFolder/51.jpg,
```

Comment: Perhaps showing the headers of your csv file can help to help ?

Comment: How many columns of names in each file?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CSV is just a list of paths with a single path on each row, you could do something like this:

```
import csv
from shutil import copyfile

def load_paths(filename):
    pathdict = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        a = 0
        for row in filereader:
            pathdict[a] = ''.join(row)
            a += 1
        csvfile.close()
        return pathdict

srcpaths = load_paths('srcfile.csv')
dstpaths = load_paths('dstfile.csv')

for a in range(len(srcpaths)):
    copyfile(srcpaths[a],dstpaths[a])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy genfromtxt as follows,

```
import numpy as np
from shutil import copyfile

srcdf = np.genfromtxt('./src.csv', dtype='S')
destdf = np.genfromtxt('./dest.csv', dtype='S')

assert len(srcdf) == len(destdf)
for n in range(len(srcdf)):
    copyfile(srcdf[n],destdf[n])
```